# Kill bash/terminal/tty window/session from another terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, kill, tty

`Linux ThinkPad-E480 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have just encountered with the next situation: `suspend` command do nothing but blocking an input. I tried `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-d`, `ctrl-z`, but it's not helping.

P.S. i'm called it `tty` because every bash window returns another value by `tty` command.
[image: proof]

Comment: Do you know what `suspend` does? (see `help suspend`, note what it says about `SIGCONT`). A straightforward solution is not to invoke `suspend` if you don't want what it does. If you think `suspend` is a solution to some other problem then [please state the other problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `suspend` makes the shell send a SIGSTOP to itself. To resume a stopped process you must **send a SIGCONT** signal to it. All other signals, even SIGKILL, are queued and will only be processed after the process has been resumed with SIGCONT.

If you had several shells nested (e.g. if you were running `su` or `sudo -s`), the control would return to the parent shell and you could resume the child using `fg`.

But when there is no parent shell which would implement job control, you'll need to send that SIGCONT manually:

```
kill -CONT <pid>
pkill -CONT bash
```

---

Each graphical terminal, or each ssh connection, or each tmux pane, indeed has its own tty. Even though they allocate "pseudo-terminals" with 'pts' in their name, those are tty devices for all intents and purposes.